# How can I set a javascript bookmarklet as a homepage?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I've written a **bookmarklet** that I'd like to set as my homepage.  It's simple, and looks like this:

```
javascript:location.href='http://somesitetoload.com';someJS();
```

I can copy and paste this into Chrome's URL bar without a problem, and it seems to run fine, opening `somepagetoload.com`. I can invoke it as a bookmarklet without a problem, too.

However, if I stick this into the `homepage` section of Chrome, nothing happens when I click the `home` button.

Why doesn't Chrome want to let me use my Javascript as a homepage?  How can I use this javascript bookmarklet as a homepage so that it runs every time I open Chrome?

I expect one solution is to embed it in an external HTML page, but that seems unnecessary, and I'm also not clear on how `someJS()` would ever be invoked.

EDIT: Further investigation has revealed that, in fact, this Javascript won't work at all -- once location.href is invoked, no further javascript will run. Moreover, Chrome doesn't let you run javascript from the URL from its start page - only from a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript in the address bar is disabled by default on Chrome.

Comment: hmm, I don't think this is the case.  javascript:alert('hi') seems to work fine.  it seems more likely the issue is due to no javascript being runnable from Chrome's default 'web store' page that opens when you make new tabs?